# Rows to Columns (Pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the following structure:

```
cpf         ddd phone       type    origin
11111111111 83  81021111    M       SERASA
11111111111 83  87472222    M       SERASA
11111111111 83  81023333    M       TRANSUNION
11111111111 83  88724444    M       TRANSUNION
11111111111 83  87475555    M       TRANSUNION
22222222222 43  36271111    F       SERASA
22222222222 44  36272222    F       SERASA
22222222222 43  36273333    F       TRANSUNION
22222222222 43  36284444    F       TRANSUNION
33333333333 51  51811111    F       SERASA
33333333333 51  56212222    F       SERASA
33333333333 51  96213333    M       SERASA
```

I need to "denormalise" this table, so each CPF will have just one row, something like that:

```
CPF         DDD_1 PHONE_1   TYPE_1 ORIGIN_1 DDD_2 PHONE_2   TYPE_2 ORIGIN_2 DDD_3 PHONE_3   TYPE_3  ORIGIN_3    DDD_4 PHONE_4   TYPE_4  ORIGIN_4    DDD_5   PHONE_5  TYPE_5 ORIGIN_5
11111111111 83    81021111  M      SERASA   83    87472222  M      SERASA   83    81023333  M       TRANSUNION  83    88724444  M       TRANSUNION  83      8747555  M      TRANSUNION
22222222222 43    36271111  F      SERASA   44    36272222  F      SERASA   43    36273333  F       TRANSUNION  43    36274444  F       TRANSUNION  NULL    NULL     NULL   NULL
33333333333 51    51811111  F      SERASA   51    56212222  F      SERASA   51    96213333  M       SERASA      NULL  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL     NULL   NULL
```

A teammate suggested using `Pivot` + `Unpivot`, but I didn't find how to use it, because I don't have a field that defines the columns, and also don't have aggregates (sum, count, etc.).

I made it with a few data (100 rows) using joins with the table itself, but this solution doesn't work due to the amount of data (the table has 33 million rows).

Right now I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I don't have a field that defines the columns" that's the first step - create a query using `ROWNUM` that identifies the row number within each `cpf` group.  Then pivoting will be a lot easier

Comment: I prefer crosstabs to the native pivot. I find the syntax far less obtuse and the performance is usually a little bit better. Here is a great article on crosstabs. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/ And if you need to make this dynamic you can use dynamic crosstabs. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Answer (score 1):

Questions are more likely to recieve an answer if you have a go yourself.  SO will help you with code errors and problems, but isn't a code writing service.

That said; it just so happens I have a working example...

The example uses your sample records, wrapped in a table variable.  Table variables make sharing data much easier, as do services like [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and [Stack Data Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/#).  You're more likely to get an answer if you make it easier for the community to help you.

**Example Data**

```
/* I've used a table variable to make 
 * sharing the example data easier.
 */
DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
        cpf         VARCHAR(11),
        ddd         INT,
        phone       VARCHAR(10),
        [type]      VARCHAR(1),
        origin      VARCHAR(10)
    )
;

-- Demo values taken from OP.
INSERT INTO @Table
    (
        cpf,
        ddd,
        phone,
        [type],
        origin
    )
VALUES
    ('11111111111', 83,  '87472222',    'M',   'SERASA'),
    ('11111111111', 83,  '81023333',    'M',   'TRANSUNION'),
    ('11111111111', 83,  '88724444',    'M',   'TRANSUNION'),
    ('11111111111', 83,  '87475555',    'M',   'TRANSUNION'),
    ('22222222222', 43,  '36271111',    'F',   'SERASA'),
    ('22222222222', 44,  '36272222',    'F',   'SERASA'),
    ('22222222222', 43,  '36273333',    'F',   'TRANSUNION'),
    ('22222222222', 43,  '36284444',    'F',   'TRANSUNION'),
    ('33333333333', 51,  '51811111',    'F',   'SERASA'),
    ('33333333333', 51,  '56212222',    'F',   'SERASA'),
    ('33333333333', 51,  '96213333',    'M',   'SERASA')
;
```

To move your rows into columns I've sequenced the records.  Using [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) I've assigned a 1 to the first record for each *cpf*, a 2 to the second and so on.  To avoid endlessly retyping ROW_NUMBER() I've turned the result into a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx).  CTEs are a great way of creating temporary, reusable datasets.  The final step is to move the records numbered 1 into the first set of columns, those numbered 2 into the second set, etc.

Moving the rows into columns probably deserves a more detailed explanation.  I've used [CASE expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to conditional move the values, based on the sequence number returned by ROW_NUMBER().  I've then [GROUPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) the results by cpf.  Wrapping each case expression with a [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) returns the required result.

**CASEing rows into columns**

```
/* The records from each cdp are numbered.
 * The numbering is used to pivot the rows into
 * columns.
 */
WITH Sequenced AS
    (
        -- This CTE numbers the records for each cpf.
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cpf ORDER BY phone) AS rn,
            *
        FROM
            @Table
    )
SELECT
    cpf,
    -- First set of columns.
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ddd       ELSE NULL END)  AS ddd_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN phone     ELSE NULL END)  AS phone_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [type]    ELSE NULL END)  AS type_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN origin    ELSE NULL END)  AS origin_1,

    -- Second set of columns.
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ddd       ELSE NULL END)  AS ddd_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN phone     ELSE NULL END)  AS phone_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [type]    ELSE NULL END)  AS type_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN origin    ELSE NULL END)  AS origin_2,

    -- Third set of columns.
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ddd       ELSE NULL END)  AS ddd_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN phone     ELSE NULL END)  AS phone_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [type]    ELSE NULL END)  AS type_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN origin    ELSE NULL END)  AS origin_3,

    -- Fourth set of columns
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ddd       ELSE NULL END)  AS ddd_4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN phone     ELSE NULL END)  AS phone_4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN [type]    ELSE NULL END)  AS type_4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN origin    ELSE NULL END)  AS origin_4
FROM
    Sequenced
GROUP BY 
    cpf
;
```

**Results**

This is a lot to take in.  Let's break down the steps.  First the CTE adds a partitioned row number:

```
rn  cpf     ddd phone       type    origin
1   11111111111 83  81021111    M   SERASA
2   11111111111 83  87472222    M   SERASA
3   11111111111 83  81023333    M   TRANSUNION
4   11111111111 83  88724444    M   TRANSUNION
5   11111111111 83  87475555    M   TRANSUNION
1   22222222222 43  36271111    F   SERASA
2   22222222222 44  36272222    F   SERASA
3   22222222222 43  36273333    F   TRANSUNION
4   22222222222 43  36284444    F   TRANSUNION
1   33333333333 51  51811111    F   SERASA
2   33333333333 51  56212222    F   SERASA
3   33333333333 51  96213333    M   SERASA
```

Next the case expressions move rows into columns, based on the row number.  I've only include some of the columns and rows to make this easier to read.

```
rn  cpf         phone_1    phone_2    phone_3
1   11111111111 81021111   NULL       NULL
2   11111111111 NULL       87472222   NULL
3   11111111111 NULL       NULL       87475555
```

Finally the grouping removes the excess rows.  The max function favours content over nulls.  Again I've removed rows and columns to make this easier to follow.

```
rn  cpf         phone_1    phone_2    phone_3
1   11111111111 81021111   87472222   87475555
2   22222222222 36271111   36272222   36273333
...
```

Comment: This is just my first question here, I'll do my best to make easier for everyone to help (perhaps with my own code on the question and a query to generate example data). Your solution worked fine, I was worried about the time it would get to run but took just 10 minutes. Thank you!

Comment: How many records are there in your table? I only ask because 10 mins sounds slow. Might be able to help you speed that up.

Comment: There are 33 million records in the original table, and 7.5 million records in the resulting table (I used an Insert Into right before the select to populate it). As the process will be running once a month, 10 minutes is ok, but I understand your point, and would really appreciate your help if you have any suggestions on how to make it faster. Thanks again!